# How to configure SpringCloud Eureka instance to point to https on non standard port

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am using Spring boot/cloud with Actuator, and I annotate Application class with @EnableEurekaClient, the applications comes up and registers correctly with Eureka server.

However, because I configure my application to run on https, and on port 8444, 
Eureka instance is not registered with correct protocol, instead it is using http.

example from http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/ gives me

```
<homePageUrl>http://localhost:8444/</homePageUrl>
<statusPageUrl>http://localhost:8444/info</statusPageUrl>
<healthCheckUrl>http://localhost:8444/health</healthCheckUrl>
```

Comment: Have use set `eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true`?

Comment: I read NetFlix code, where Eureka instance is hard coded as http unless explicit absolute Url is set as eureka.instance.status-page-url is set

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `secureHomePageUrl` or `secureStatusPageUrl` - only `secureHealthCheckUrl` exists. Check `com.netflix.appinfo.EurekaInstanceConfig` for the properties that are actually transmitted to the server when an Eureka client registers.

However, having the home/status/health page urls not showing the HTTPS protocol doesn't mean your instance isn't properly registered. What matters is whether or not the secure port is enabled. Check the following properties in your client configuration:

```
eureka.instance.securePort: 443
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled: true
```

The registry information obtained from http://eureka:8761/eureka/apps should reflect those values.

You should remember that the `homePageUrl` and `statusPageUrl` are not used by neither Eureka or Ribbon. They are apparently provided only for *informational purpose*. However, the `healthCheckUrl` and `secureHealthCheckUrl` may be used by some load balancing rules or other health reporting systems. This is probably why a "secure" version of that property exists but not for the other...